# which method is better String.equalIgnoreCase or StringUtils.equalIgnoreCase

Tags: java, apache-commons

i have been asked to use `StringUtils.equalIgnoreCase` method rather than `String.equalIgnoreCase`
can anyone tell me the reason why ?

what is the difference between them ?

Comment: Who has asked you to do this, and what reason did they give?

Comment: And what is `server.jar`?!

Comment: Tell them `Do not compare Native methods with Third-party library method.`

Answer (score 4):

The StringUtils's method is nullsafe (i.e) if either of the two elements is `null`, it will not throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I generally let people fix minor things like this if it's still within the grace period.

Comment: Although it seems obvious, with StringUtils the two elements may be null, whereas String can not be so.